# read from ftp socket in vxworks

Tags: c, exception, fwrite, vxworks

I want to read data from a socket and write them to a fuile with fwrite but I keep getting an exception. My code:

```
MyFile = fopen ("flash:/ngfm.bin","wb");
if (MyFile != NULL) {

    while ((nBytes = read (dataSock, buf, sizeof (buf))) > 0) {
        ByteCount++;
        if (ByteCount %10)
            printf(".");
        if (ByteCount %100)
                    printf("\n");
        fwrite( buf, sizeof(buf), nBytes, MyFile );
    }
    printf("%d Bytes written to flash:/ngfm.bin!\n", ByteCount);
    fclose( MyFile );
}
close (dataSock);
```

This is on `vxworks` and my device flash: exists and is writeable! I did the following on the shell:

```
JPAX-DP> mf = fopen("flash:/test","w")
New symbol "mf" added to kernel symbol table.
mf = 0x26e75e90: value = 636346784 = 0x25ede1a0
JPAX-DP> fputs("TEST",mf)
value = 0 = 0x0
JPAX-DP> fclose(mf)
value = 0 = 0x0
JPAX-DP> ls("flash:/")
flash:/switch_demo_rem.vxs
flash:/switch_demo_lb_on.vxs
flash:/switch_demo_lb_off.vxs
flash:/switch_demo1b.vxs
flash:/switch_demo1a.vxs
flash:/switch_demo.vxs
flash:/sanity.soc
flash:/rc.soc
flash:/protection_init.vxs
flash:/pack_demo.vxs
flash:/init.vxs
flash:/config.bcm
flash:/BCM56440_B0_0.srec
flash:/BCM56440_A0_1.srec
flash:/BCM56440_A0_0.srec
flash:/jpax_msg.log
flash:/jpax_err.log
flash:/ngfm.bin
flash:/test
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "buf" is declared properly and is big enough.